# Querying Datetime field in SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with data type as  datetime2 NOT NULL. The date is in format is '10/30/2013' and the below query does not pull the info.The date in the table is stored like this
'2011-12-25 21:28:58'

```
 SELECT  source_code,AMT,PURID
 FROM SOURCEINFO  WHERE  
 DATE_INSERTED BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/01/2011') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/30/2013')
 AND   (SOURCE_CODE IS NOT NULL)  
 GROUP BY SOURCE_CODE
```

Comment: No errors and no results

Comment: At least you should get: *Column `'AMT,PURID'` are invalid in the select list because they are not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.* Please show some data.

Answer (score 0):

first datetime string can be either `10 jan 2011` or `Nov 1 2011`, I suggest you to use YYYY-MM-DD format always or use style argument in convert function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

`CONVERT (datetime, '10/01/2011', 101)`